# Do characters carry over when playing Old Runescape?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

I want to play the old Runescape because I dislike the new combat update. After playing the game for over 6 years, and I want to play the old Runescape I am used to, but I want to keep all of my levels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.** All members start fresh at level 3 on Runescape '07. It's an entirely different game as far as the data is concerned.

Though think of the possibilities; a fresh start could be fun. Or it could be grindy. Depending on how you take it.

Comment: A fresh start will be fun, but I do not like having to stop using my Lv 60+ skills I love.

Answer (score 0):

Unionhawk's answer is correct.  [*Oldschool Runescape*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_School_RuneScape) (often called OSRS, or Runescape 2007) is completely separate from [*Runescape*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RuneScape) (commonly called RS3, Runescape 3, or EoC).  When you use your "old" *Runescape* login information on *Oldschool Runescape* for the first time, you will start a new account on Tutorial Island.  Any progress you made on *Runescape* is not lost, but separate from your *Oldschool Runescape* progress.  If you use that same login information on *Runescape*, you will begin right where you left off all that time ago.

*Runescape* has evolved into what it is today - a game with more modern graphics, a completely different combat system and interface, micro-transactions, etc.  *Oldschool Runescape* is based off of a build of Runescape from August 2007.  Back in August of 2007, there was only one version of Runescape to play (well... excluding Runescape Classic).  That version of the game has evolved into what is now *Runescape*. *Oldschool Runescape* was released in February 2013 as a fresh new game based off of that August 2007 build  mentioned before.

There are some things that are shared between the two games.  This includes:

- Your Friends list
- Your Ignored player list
- Your Display Name
- Your total days since account creation number as given to you by [Hans](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Hans)

Some things that are **not** shared between the versions:

- All stats
- All items in your inventory and bank
- Quest progress

Comment: See [Dude... where's my stats?](https://support.runescape.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360001539509-Dude-where-s-my-stats-) as posted on the Runescape official website.